# Bind partial view in MVC View using jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dom

```
I have a View as shown below

**<div id = 123 class ="Country">**
  <div class = "content">
      **<need to load partial view here>**
  </div>
**</div>**

**<div id = 234 class ="Country">**
 <div class = "content">
     **<need to load partial view here>**
  </div>

**</div>**
...
...More div's here
...
so on clicking the Country div, i need to load its inner div "content". My jQuery ajax call is like below

    $(".country").on('click', function () {
         $.ajax({
                    url: '@(Url.Action("FilesByCountry", "RelatedFiles"))', //Cont & ActionResult
                    type: "GET",
                    data: $(this).attr('id'), //getting the click id
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

            function successFunc(data) {
                **$(this).attr('id').children($('#content', data).html())**
                }

                function errorFunc(xhr, errorType, exception) {
                    alert(xhr.status +  ": " + exception);
                }
        });
    });
```

So the controller is hitting fine and it went through the PartialView in debug mode. But the partial view is not binding in Main View. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Do you get content if you use --> .html(data)?

Comment: if i put alert(data) in success then i am seeing the Partial view html binded...so now my problem is how to find/bind the id's children's "content" div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. Actually $(this) is not working inside my successFunc and was returning null always. So i modified my Javascript code to something as below.

```
$(".country").on('click', function () {
var _this = $(this);
         $.ajax({
                    url: '@(Url.Action("FilesByCountry", "RelatedFiles"))', //Cont & ActionResult
                    type: "GET",
                    data: $(this).attr('id'), //getting the click id
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

            function successFunc(data) {
                _this.find('.content').html(data);
                }

                function errorFunc(xhr, errorType, exception) {
                    alert(xhr.status +  ": " + exception);
                }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the way you are stuffing the content:

```
$(this).find('.content').html(data);
```

I think `#content` would be for the ID selector and `.content` for the class selector.

Another try is to just stuff a known div -->

```
$('#234').find('.content').html(data);
```

Or

```
$('#234').html(data);
```

Then inspect the element using dev tools F12 and see what was put inside.

Also, make sure you are injecting an html fragment. You can check the data for  `<head><body>` tags, I am sure they should not be there for what you are doing.

Comment: yes you are correct. But after correcting, I see the same behavior. The PartialView is not rendering inside content div